# Magento 1: Add Option to Shipping Address Selection

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onestepcheckout

In Magento 1 checkout page I want to add the third option In-Store Pickup with, Ship to this Address, Ship to different Address.

If the customer chooses this In-Store Pickup then any offline shipping method will be selected and tax will be calculated using custom logic according to the address of the store.